# Type assertion over object composed several times

Tags: go

Is it possible to do type assertion over any of the sub type of an object composed several times?

Example, say I have the following objects:

```
type MyResponseWriter struct {
    http.ResponseWriter
    // ...
}

type MyOtherResponseWriter struct {
    http.ResponseWriter
    // ...
}
```

I might end up with something like this:

```
rw := &MyOtherResponseWriter{ResponseWriter: &MyResponseWriter{ResponseWriter: w}}
```

Now if I have a `w http.ResponseWriter`, is it possible to 'cast' it to either a `MyOtherResponseWriter` or a `MyResponseWriter` ?

```
cw.(*MyResponseWriter) // panic: interface conversion: http.ResponseWriter is *MyOtherResponseWriter, not *MyResponseWriter
```

FWIW, my actual use case is that in a `http.Handler` I'm dealing with a `http.ResponseWriter` that's been wrapped several times and I fail to access the extra method that interests me, and the reason I want to do this is to allow a middleware to access data written by the handler.

Thanks

Comment: Are you just asking how to check what the type of `cw` is? Assuming you have a limited number of combinations, just switch over all the possibilities.

Comment: @JimB I fail to see how, switching on `w.(type)` only gives me the latest type

Comment: If you don't know all the possible types, then there's nothing you can do except call interface methods, and you can always assert against any method set you want. How does a type switch not give you what you need? What extra method are you interested in?

Comment: Probably what I'm trying to do is awkward: I've added a method to one of the writer (say `MyResponseWriter.setStuff`) so that I can store extra data in the ResponseWriter, that is later accessed by middlewares. What I ultimately want is to pass data from the handler up to the middleware.

Comment: It's awkward but not difficult. Just type-assert each level until you get to the type (or interface) you want.

Comment: But that assumes that I know in advance the type hierarchy right? In this specific example the hierarchy is obvious, but in reality, I may have extra wrapping. A case I have is sometimes those writer are wrapped by the http.TimeoutHandler for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what type of logic you are looking for you could do something like:

```
var rw http.ResponseWriter = &MyResponseWriter{
  ResponseWriter: &MyOtherResponseWriter{}
}
cw := rw.(*MyResponseWriter).ResponseWriter.(*MyOtherResponseWriter)
```

Notice that the code always has to "know" which type of `ResponseWriter` it has.

Comment: thanks, in my case I may not necessarily know what are all the underlying types :/

Comment: The type switch can give me the underlying type (`MyOtherResponseWriter `) but here I want to access `MyResponseWriter`'s method. Looks like I'd need interfaces instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for an arbitrary method, on a field nested an arbitrary number of levels deep within your own types, you need to assert each level's type to get the candidate field.

For example, if you wanted to determine if you have an `http.Flusher` using the types shown above, you could use a function like so:

```
func getFlusher(rw http.ResponseWriter) (http.Flusher, bool) {
    switch t := rw.(type) {
    case http.Flusher:
        return t, true
    case *MyResponseWriter:
        return getFlusher(t.ResponseWriter)
    case *MyOtherResponseWriter:
        return getFlusher(t.ResponseWriter)
    default:
        return nil, false
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Li80bUzYTft

Comment: Is it possible to access `MyResponseWriter` methods in this specific case?
That's what I'd want but probably as you said I'd need an interface for `MyResponseWriter`.

Comment: @Sylvain: Of course, you have a concrete `*MyResponseWriter` within the type switch, and you could also assert to whatever method set you want. You could return whatever type you want as well, this was just an example of using a common pre-defined interface.